# Can't get python to write to a text file, gives me an empty file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get my program to write a list to a text file. I've changed it to a string and it creates the text file but it is empty. Also I got it to print the variable I'm trying to write to the text file and it comes out exactly as it is supposed to.

```
import string
import re
wholeLine = ""
file = open("bowlingscores.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    wholeLine += line
    scores = re.findall('\d+', wholeLine)
    names = re.findall('\D+', wholeLine)
file.close()
scores = list(map(int,scores))
validScores = [x for x in scores if 300 >= x >= 0]
average = sum(validScores) / len(validScores)
numScores = len(scores)
output = []
for i in range(numScores):
    if scores[i] == 300:
        output.append(names[i])
        output.append("\nperfect")
    if scores[i] == average:
        output.append(names[i])
        output.append("\naverage")
    if scores[i] < average:
        output.append(names[i])
        output.append("\nbelow average")
    if scores[i] > average:
        if scores[i] <300:
            output.append(names[i])
            output.append("\nabove average")
    if scores[i] > 300:
        output.append(names[i])
        output.append("\ninvalid score")
outputFile = open('bowlingaverages.txt', 'w')
outputFile.write(str(output))
outputFile.close
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should convert your output which is a list to string properly, try using

```
outputFile = open('bowlingaverages.txt', 'w')
outputFile.write(''.join(output))
outputFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you'd write to the file with output (which is a list):

```
with open('bowlingaverages.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(''.join(output))
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I edited the code as follows and had a friend run it on his computer and it did as it was supposed to, however still does not work on my computer. I am now more confused than I was in the first place. Is it possibly a problem with a different program?

```
import string
import re
wholeLine = ""
file = open("bowlingscores.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    wholeLine += line
    scores = re.findall('\d+', wholeLine)
    names = re.findall('\D+', wholeLine)
file.close()
scores = list(map(int,scores))
validScores = [x for x in scores if 300 >= x >= 0]
average = sum(validScores) / len(validScores)
numScores = len(scores)
output = []
for i in range(numScores):
    if scores[i] == 300:
        output.append(names[i])
        output.append("\tperfect\n")
    if scores[i] == average:
        output.append(names[i])
        output.append("\taverage\n")
    if scores[i] < average:
        output.append(names[i])
        output.append("\tbelow average\n")
    if scores[i] > average:
        if scores[i] <300:
            output.append(names[i])
            output.append("\tabove average\n")
    if scores[i] > 300:
        output.append(names[i])
        output.append("\tinvalid score\n")
outputFile = open('bowlingaverages.txt', 'w')
for item in output:
    outputFile.write(item)
outputFile.close
print(output)
```

Comment: looks to me that the problem may be in the first loop, there you overwrite the `score` and all the other variables each time, therefore it only contain the value from the last line, and if that line is empty or get nothing from it, you get nothing as result too